# Where is the ambiguity in this Java method call?

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, variadic-functions, ambiguity

I am getting a "reference to make is ambiguous" compiler error that I don't understand.

I have these two methods

```
public static <T> T make(String name, Class<T> parentClass, 
                         boolean rethrowRuntimeExceptions, 
                         Object... params) throws DLException

 public static <T> T make(String name, Class<T> parentClass,
                          Object... params) throws DLException
```

This line of code is being marked as ambiguous

```
  String className = "clsNme";
  String one = "1";
  String two = "2";     
  SimpleFactory.make(className, Object.class, false, one, two);
```

Here is the error

```
both method <T#1>make(String,Class<T#1>,boolean,Object...) in SimpleFactory and method <T#2>make(String,Class<T#2>,Object...) in SimpleFactory match
    [javac]   where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    [javac]     T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>make(String,Class<T#1>,boolean,Object...)
    [javac]     T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>make(String,Class<T#2>,Object...)
```

Doesn't the presence of the boolean parameter make the first method a closer match than the second?

If it matters, this is part of a PowerMock test  Here is the complete method

```
public void makeCallsMakeWithFalse() throws Throwable {
  Object expected = mock(Object.class);
  String className = "clsNme";

  String one = "1";
  String two = "2";

  spy(SimpleFactory.class);

  doReturn(expected).when(SimpleFactory.class);
  SimpleFactory.make(className, Object.class, false, one, two);  // causes error

  Object observed = SimpleFactory.make(className, Object.class, one, two); // doesn't cause error
  assertEquals(expected, observed);

  verifyStatic();
  SimpleFactory.make(className, Object.class, false, one, two);  // causes error
```

}

If it helps:  I'm using javac 1.8.0_77, Mokito 1.10.19, and Powermock 1.6.3.

Comment: Based on the solutions below, I addressed the compiler errors by changing the `boolean` parameter to `Boolean`.  This means that users have to pass `Boolean.TRUE` instead of `true`; but, that seems less obnoxious than having them type `new Object[]{a, b,c}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies in

```
Object... params
```

When calling `SimpleFactory.make(className, Object.class, false, one, two);`
Java will not know whether to box the "false" into a Boolean object and pass it as the first argument of the "params" varargs array (Boolean extends Object) and use

```
make(String name, Class<T> parentClass, Object... params)
```

or whether to call

```
make(String name, Class<T> parentClass, boolean rethrowRuntimeExceptions, Object... params)
```

since that signature can also accept a boolean before the params varargs.

Hence why it's ambiguous, both method signatures are applicable.

Comment: I think it is worth noting that the ambiguity comes in because Java ranks varargs and autoboxing equally.  Most of us would expect the use of a literal  boolean to make choice 1 above a better match; but, because the autoboxing is on the same "level" Java won't choose.

Comment: That's a poor choice IMO. The call with the boolean value should be preferred.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler first tries to find a matching signature thst does not involve autoboxing/unboxing or *variable arity invocation*. Variable arity invocation is when you invoke a varargs method by passing a parameter list as the last argument (as opposed to an array).

In your case, both involve variable arity invocation. When this happens, the most specific overload is chosen. For your situation, neither is considered more specific as defined in the JLS. This is essentially because neither of the types `boolean` and `Object` is a subtype of the other.

Simplifying your example a bit, the following does not compile.

```
static void foo(boolean b, Object... arr) {

}

static void foo(Object... arr) {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    foo(true);
}
```

The first version will not accept a single argument of type `Object` and the second will not accept a single argument of type `boolean`. Therefore neither is more specific. (Autoboxing only makes it *look* as if you can pass a `boolean` as an argument of type `Object`).

On the other hand, if you replace `boolean` by `Boolean`, it does compile because `Boolean` is a subtype of `Object`.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why `make(String Class<T>, boolean, Object...)` won't be selected for `make(className, Object.class, false, one, two)` since this one would be the most specific one. And OPs code works fine for me.

Comment: @Tom I don't know what you mean. My answer explains why neither is more specific, doesn't it? If the code compiles for you, it's a compiler bug.

Comment: I believe that the compiler error is new with the improved typing in Java 8.  My code compiled fine before I upgraded to Java 8.

Comment: @Zack Sounds like a bug fix. I don't think the relevant part of the JLS (choosing the most specific method) has changed since 1.5.

Comment: Yes, from what I've read it was a bug fix ("marketed" as an improvement to the adherence to the spec).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the compiler doesn't know if you want the boolean parameter to be included in params or not. I could either call the function with 4 parameters and pass the boolean in as the 3rd parameter or it could call the function with 3 parameters and add the boolean to the Object... params. The compiler doesn't know what to do because of this ambiguity. Let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 1):

Problem lies with

```
Object... params
```

To fix the ambiguity - change the code like below

To call

```
public static <T> T make(String name, Class<T> parentClass, 
                         boolean rethrowRuntimeExceptions, 
                         Object... params) throws DLException
```

call it like this:

```
  SimpleFactory.make(className, Object.class, false, new Object[]{one, two});
```

And

To call

```
 public static <T> T make(String name, Class<T> parentClass,
                          Object... params) throws DLException
```

call it like this:

```
  SimpleFactory.make(className, Object.class, new Object[]{false,one, two});
```

Comment: @Tom: Thanks for catching it. Updated the post.

Comment: That works; but, the intent of the varargs is to make the methods easier for the users.  Having to wrap up the varargs defeats that purpose.  In my case, changing `boolean` to `Boolean` fixed the problem with less "extra typing"